# How can I disable Control-W in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

**Update:** While the following should still work (I no longer have access to a Windoze box), [pyrospade](https://superuser.com/users/153127/pyrospade) [points out](https://superuser.com/questions/130109/how-can-i-disable-control-w-in-windows-xp?noredirect=1#comment745133_130109) that there is a way to do this directly from within Console2 nowadays. I have no idea if that's accurate but I wanted to point it out. Thanks!

Now, on with the show!

---

I'm an Emacs/Mac user trapped on Windows at work and I often type Control-W from muscle memory to delete a word and thus by mistake kill the entire window, including everything that I was working on.  This a particularly egregious problem for Console2 as I run GNU Screen and am often doing many things at once.

Is there any way to completely disable Control-W or remap it to something that is far harder to type?

Thanks!

**Update**: The solution I ended up with is the following:

My AutoHotkey configuration now looks like this.

```
#IfWinNotActive emacs@XXXXXXXXXXXX
    ^w::Return
#IfWinActive
```

Cause let's be honest, I was really doing this just because I use emacs. :)

Comment: Good thinking with the window title conditional there.

Comment: For future readers, not that there is a way to change the setting in Console2 - Edit > Settings > Hotkeys - find "Close tab", click the Clear button, then the Assign button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this comment:

> To actually answer your question...Search for "key mapper" on google.  Among
>   others it will lead you to sharewareconnection.com which lists many (some
>   reviewed) mappers.  One that is listed there that may be what you need is
>   http://www.easysofts.com.cn/en/, but I can't be positive from the
>   description, however you can ask them.  At least this will point you in the
>   right direction.  Take the usual precautions when downloading and installing
>   shareware.
>
> I believe that this will allow you to disable CTRL-W on a Windows level (not
>   just IE), but perhaps that is what you meant by "I don't *ever* want to use
>   it."

on [this post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31562780/how-do-i-disable-ctrlw-i.aspx).

I've not investigated the link fully as yet, but it looks like it (or something like it) is what you want.

Comment: It seems one could also easily write an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) script to intercept the hotkey and do nothing with it. It looks like `^c::Return` would do the trick.

Comment: I have two PCs at work; one w/ admin rights and own w/o.  I ended up going with [How To Geek's Suggestions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) for the box that I have admin rights to and with @Nathaniel's suggestion on the machine w/o.

Comment: See my update.  I'm now not using a registry hack.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the combo altogether for the whole system is not necessary; just open Console2, go to Edit->Settings->Hotkeys, and change the Close Tab hotkey to something else.

Comment: The problem is just particularly offensive in Console2.  It's till pretty offensive everywhere else. :)  However, this will at least relieve part of the paint point.

Comment: “Everwhere else”? Like where? The Start Menu? The desktop? Why are you pressing Ctrl-W to select a word in those places?

Answer (score 0):

This article describes various means and programs : ["Remapping the Keyboard Layout in Windows"](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm), 
either yourself via the registry, or by using the utilities SharpKeys or KeyTweak.